# Java and SQLite and Android: Array of different objects

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm developing in Android (SQLite) but I think this is a Java issue.
I want to update a Table, TABLE_GASTOS, my WHERE clause is "(col_MES+" =? AND " +col_ANO+"=?")" and the problem is on the args.

```
db.update(TABLE_GASTOS, values, (col_MES+" =? AND " +col_ANO+"=?"), args);
```

How can I do something like (have an array of diferent types of objects):

```
**String[] args = new String[]{gasto.getMes(),gasto.getAno()};**
```

If
**gasto.getAno** returns an Integer.

**gasto.getMes** returns a String.

in order that my last argument on db.update be **args**.

Comment: how about `gasto.getAno().ToString()`?

Comment: @IanSellar, no, because on Database Ano is Int and Mes is String

Comment: Well what is the error you are getting exactly? If you could add that to your question it might help.

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Show errors. And whats in your `ContentValues` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using SQL parameters is a good idea generally, the Android database API allows only strings.

Insert the integer value directly into the SQL:

```
db.update(TABLE_GASTOS, values,
          col_MES+" =? AND " +col_ANO+"="+gasto.getAno(),
          new String[]{gasto.getMes()});
```